# Google Maps solution for MonoDroid

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin.android

Does anyone have a Google Maps solution for MonoDroid? To make it work, we need to inherit from MapActivity (com.google.android.maps).

I see on the MonoDroid Roadmap that this feature is coming to MonoDroid 1.1, but there's no release date yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this time, the maps API is not already bound for you.  You will have to do the binding yourself.  An example is available here:

https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples

Comment: Thanks, jpobst. I'll give it a go today.

Comment: Works great, just needed to recreate my debug.keystore

Comment: Does this mean I have to write all the code in java? Or can I still get the mapview from my C# code and handle placing pins and stuff like that?

Answer (score 1):

Since the previous post, they have now bound the google maps in the latest release.  Download the latest API from xamarin and an example is here:

https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/MapsDemo